# Suma de vectores no da el resultado esperado

Tags: python

quiero hacer la suma de dos vectores y la verdad no me estaría andando el codigo. ¿Me ayudan?

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
""" 
Dados dos arreglos A y b N<15 elementos cada uno,
 calcular un arreglo C tal que c=a+b y Mostrarlo.

"""
va=[]
vb=[]
vc=[]
n=3 # tiene que ser n<15 (5 pq quiero)

for i in range (0,n+1,1): # cargo los de uno y despues los de otro . De lo contrario tardaria mas!!1
    va.append(int(input("ingresar los datos de los arreglos A ")))

for i in range (0,n+1,1):    
    vb.append(int(input("ingresar los datos de los arreglos B")))


for i in range (0,n+1,1):
    vc[i] = va[i] + vb[i]

print ("",vc[i])
```

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GLvqr7

Comment: Hola. ¿No sale porque te arroja un error?, ¿cuál es el resultado de tu print?

Comment: Buenas tardes Ale, que calculo te da exactamente y que esperas? saludos

Comment: ¿No será que el print final debe ser `print(vc)`?

Comment: @abulafia eso, o le falta una identación.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esta solución con la función `append`.

Ejemplo:

```
for i in range (0,n+1,1):
    vc.append(va[i] + vb[i])

print(vc)
```

Comment: Mira aquí [las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @MauricioAriasOlave